# Why is Eigen matrix to C array conversion giving garbage values for the first two indices?

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

I have an Eigen matrix to be converted to a C array. I can replicate the issue with the following example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int *test()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXi arr = Eigen::MatrixXi::Ones(6,1);
    // just to check
    arr(4)=3;
    arr(5)=19;
    return arr.data();
}

int main()
{
    int *c_arr;
    c_arr = test();

    for (int i=0; i<6;++i)
    {
        std::cout << c_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
0
1
1
3
19
```

Now if I print the converted C array values from within the `test` function the values are correct. However if I print the values from `main` (as shown above) the first two indices are always garbage. So I am wondering what is happening in the function call? I have tried this with different Eigen matrices (types, sizes) and I get the same result.

Comment: arr is destroyed when test() exits, so c_arr becomes invalid:(

Comment: If you must have a `c array` your best bet would be to use `malloc` to create a new array and `memcpy` the contents.  Remember to `free` the array after you are done using it.

Comment: I used the same format, without using Eigen, and my array returns just fine.  I am guessing it is within Eignen.

Comment: @jdl You're saying that you allocated the memory in `test` and returned the pointer without deleting it? That makes perfect sense, however is not relevant when discussing objects that are destroyed when leaving the relevant scope.

Comment: @MartinJames so silly of me, duh!. In my actual code I am already copying the data. I was just thinking of a way to do this without involving copies.

Comment: Wel you could allocate arr with new and retun *arr.  That would eliminate the bulk data copy at the cost of extending the lifetime of arr.   It kinda depends on whether you need the hassle of managing the lifetime of arr and how much data would need to be copied otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start by saying I'm not 100% familiar with the Eigen library (just downloaded it to look at it out of curiosity) and it's documentation is a bit lacking but your problem is a fundamental C problem that can be remedied a few ways.

First we'll start by explaining what's happening in your code to give garbage values:

```
int *test()
{
    /* create an auto scoped variable on the stack;
       this variable is only "visible" to this function
       and any references to it or it's underlying data
       outside the scope of this function will result
       in "undefined behaviour" */
    Eigen::MatrixXi arr = Eigen::MatrixXi::Ones(6,1);
    arr(4)=3;
    arr(5)=19;
    /* arr.data() is defined as returning a pointer to the scalar underlying type (or
    a C-style array in other words). Regardless of the type being returned, it is pointer based
    and you are returning a pointer to a location in memory, not the actual data being held in
    the memory. */
    return arr.data();
} /* the variable arr is destroyed here since we left function scope and the return value (the pointer location)
is put in the return register and "program flow" is returned back to the main function where the pointer being
returned now points to "invalid" memory */

int main()
{
    int *c_arr; // create a pointer type that can reference int types
    c_arr = test(); // point it to the result of the test function (see notes above)
    /* c_arr now points to a memory location returned from test, but since the
    arr variable no longer exists here, when you go through and print the values pointed
    to at those memory locations you will get what is at those locations and could be "anything"
    except a valid reference to the original arr variable and it's underlying data. */

    for (int i=0; i<6;++i)
    {
        std::cout << c_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So that's the *why*, as for how to fix it there are a couple of ways to go about your problem; one is to pass the return array in as a variable in to your `test` function (e.g. `void test(int*& val)`), you could then choose to allocate new memory to the variable in the test function, or assume the user has already done so, and must also assume the user will clean up after themselves and call `delete[]` (not just `delete` since you're operating on arrays of data).

But this has many caveats of needing to know how much space to allocate and being sure to deallocate when done. I'm not sure why you specifically need a C-style array but since you're using C++, it might be more prudent if you use some of the STL and container functions available to you to help you out, example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Core>

std::vector<int> test()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXi arr = Eigen::MatrixXi::Ones(6,1);
    arr(4)=3;
    arr(5)=19;
    // we need the size so we know how big of a container to allocate
    std::size_t sz = arr.innerSize() * arr.outerSize();
    std::vector<int> ret(sz);
    // get a temporary C array pointer so we can reference the data
    int* tmp = arr.data();
    // copy from tmp[0] to tmp[sz] and insert the data into the first element of ret
    std::copy(tmp, tmp+sz, ret.begin());
    // return the (copied) data
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> c_arr = test();
    // c_arr now points to valid data it holds and can be iterated on
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < c_arr.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << c_arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    // if you need a C-style array from here, you can easily copy the data
    // from the vector to your C-array
    return 0;
}
```

I looked into using the [`cast()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a660200abaf1fc4b888330a37d6132b76) function of the class, but could not quite figure out the syntax to make it less painful than just copying it the above way since it looks like you'd have to call the `cast` function to a differnt `Eigen` type and then cast again from there, but know there is a `cast` function and other methods to get the underlying data of the `MatrixX` classes if you need access to it.

I hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and putting the effort. This is what I ended up doing. I mainly use Eigen, however currently I am linking my code with a third party C library.